# Go GXUI - how to set TextBox size?

Tags: user-interface, go, textbox, size, gxui

I'm currently trying to figure out how to set a Go GXUI TextBox size. I tried:

```
textBox := theme.CreateTextBox()
textBox.SetText("")
textBox.SetSize(math.Size{W: 300, H: 300})
```

But it doesn't appear to be working - I'm getting a narrow rectangular bar instead. When I change the text, it expands downwards, but not to the sides.

Comment: this belongs on the issue tracker.

Comment: as the web developed mush, html/css/js/mvc framework is the best GUI system now. i'd rather to running a local http server background and do the GUI with browser.

Comment: @JiangYD It's not ideal to expose a web frontend for an application relying on high security.

Comment: front mean just front

Answer (score 0):

Did you try goroutine ?

```
go func(){
    driver.Call(func(){
        textBox.SetSize(math.Size{W: 300, H: 300})
    })
}()
```